# Не могу запарсить html страницу

Tags: python, beautiful-soup

при парсинге страницы мне выдаёт пустой список, но код 0. Помогите решить проблему.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

HEADERS = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9'
}
books = []


book = input("Send book name: ")
url = 'https://bookfinder.com.ua/search/'+book+'/all/relevance/1'

content = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS)
soup = BeautifulSoup(content.text, 'html.parser')

ausers = soup.find_all('li', class_='itemscope')
print(ausers)
```

Comment: Сайт динамический. Html-код страницы состоит только из хидера, строки поиска и футера. Все остальное строится динамически

Comment: И как его парсить? Через какой то селениум?

Comment: попробуйте открыть ссылку /api/books?query=dune в браузере. Может и не стоит изобретать велосипед?

Comment: ну если не знаете как парсить через requests, то селениум не плохая альтернатива. BeautifulSoup на сайте который вы пытаете спарсить бесполезен

Comment: У сайта есть апи, который отдает готовый json с книгами. Стоит нажать F12 и изучить запросы. А не пытаться спарсить html

Answer (score 2):

```
import requests

book = input()
url = f"https://bookfinder.com.ua/api/books?query={book}"
resp = requests.get(url).json()

for x in resp:
    print(x['title'])
    print(x['price'], x['currency'])
    print(x['url'])
```